# AngularJS filter by multiple (but not all) values with a single field

Tags: angularjs

How do I filter angularJS objects with a single field by multiple values? 
Lets say object contains of `person.id` `person.firstName` `person.LastName` `person.birthday`
what I want is to have a single search field to filter by `person.firstName` or `person.lastName` or `person.id` but do not filter by `person.birthday` 
how do I achieve that?

Comment: Do you want to display it as Table and filter?

Comment: Yes I'm displaying it as a list in a table. currently using multiple input fields for that and ` ng-repeat="task in filtered = ( taskList | filter:query )` to display them

Comment: Can you create a plunkr or jsfiddle? So others can check it. It takes time to build from scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would generally create your own filter for this:

## [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/6afapy7jPchyNebuk1PE?p=preview)

**MARKUP:**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <label>Search:
    <input ng-model="searchString" />
  </label>
  <div ng-repeat="person in persons | byFullName: searchString ">{{person.id}}. {{person.LastName}}, {{person.firstName}}: {{person.birthday}}</div>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('filter.demo', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.persons = [
    {id: 1, firstName: 'John', LastName: 'Doe', birthday: '01/02/2000'},
    {id: 2, firstName: 'Jane', LastName: 'Smith', birthday: '03/02/2001'},
    {id: 3, firstName: 'Mark', LastName: 'Johnson', birthday: '01/25/2001'},
    {id: 4, firstName: 'Karen', LastName: 'Smith', birthday: '04/02/2000'},
    {id: 5, firstName: 'John', LastName: 'Marker', birthday: '01/18/2003'}
  ];
}]);
app.filter('byFullName', function() {
  return function(names, search) { 
      //names is the array that is passed to the filter 
      //search is the comparison value passed to the filter 
      if(angular.isDefined(search)) {
      //make sure search is not undefined
      var results = [];
      var i;
      var searchVal = search.toLowerCase();
      for(i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        var firstName = names[i].firstName.toLowerCase();
        var lastName = names[i].LastName.toLowerCase();
        //*OPTIONAL: convert values to lowercase for case insensitive filter
        if(firstName.indexOf(searchVal) >=0 || lastName.indexOf(searchVal) >=0){
        //Loop over the array and check if the search string matches either
        //the firstName or LastName
          results.push(names[i]);
          //If there's a match, add the value to the results array that is returned
        }
      }
      return results;
    } else {
      return names;
      //If no search value is provided, we just want to return the whole array
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain the filters if you want. For example:

```
ng-repeat="item in items | filter:filterone| filter:filtertwo">
```

Comment: I guess this would work only by using multiple input fields for the filter and I need to do this by a single one or am I wrong?

Comment: So, are you taking the filter criteria from user? If it depends on user then you'll need to create a filter which handles all the functionality